# neo4j clean build failed

Tags: neo4j

I was trying to build Neo4j from https://github.com/neo4j/community.git

I'm building with `Maven 3.05` and `java 1.7.0_17`

Running command:
`mvn clean install -Dlicense.skip=true -DminimalBuild`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:licensing-maven-plugin:1.7.5:check (list-all-licenses) on project neo4j-kernel: Generated file differs from the existing file.
[ERROR] Generated: E:\neo4j\clone\gitBuild\community\kernel\target\neo4j-kernel-1.9-SNAPSHOT-NOTICE.txt
[ERROR] Existing: E:\neo4j\clone\gitBuild\community\kernel\target\..\NOTICE.txt
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:licensing-maven-plugin:1.7.5:check (list-all-licenses) on project neo4j-kernel: Generated file differs from the existing file.
Generated: E:\neo4j\clone\gitBuild\community\kernel\target\neo4j-kernel-1.9-SNAPSHOT-NOTICE.txt
Existing: E:\neo4j\clone\gitBuild\community\kernel\target\..\NOTICE.txt
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Generated file differs from the existing file.
Generated: E:\neo4j\clone\gitBuild\community\kernel\target\neo4j-kernel-1.9-SNAPSHOT-NOTICE.txt
Existing: E:\neo4j\clone\gitBuild\community\kernel\target\..\NOTICE.txt
    at org.linuxstuff.mojo.licensing.CheckMojo.generatedAndExistingDiffer(CheckMojo.java:198)
    at org.linuxstuff.mojo.licensing.CheckMojo.compareToExistingFile(CheckMojo.java:163)
    at org.linuxstuff.mojo.licensing.CheckMojo.execute(CheckMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I am building with PowerShell and the vanilla Github client for W8. Once you can run maven (adjusting the system paths etc), you should do

```
mvn install "-Dlicensing.skip"
```

Since the line endings windows adds are skrewing up the checks.

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
cd community/licensecheck-config
mvn clean install there
```

and then build the rest of the project?

Comment: Failed again. [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:licensing-maven-plugin:1.7.5:check (list-all-licenses) on project neo4j-kernel: Generated file differs from the existing file.
[ERROR] Generated: E:\neo4j\clone\gitBuild\last_build\community\kernel\target\neo4j-kernel-1.9-SNAPSHOT-NOTICE.txt
[ERROR] Existing: E:\neo4j\clone\gitBuild\last_build\community\kernel\target\..\NOTICE.txt