# build of neo4j community is failing.Why?

Tags: neo4j

i have followed all the steps as in Travis link [here](https://travis-ci.org/peterneubauer/community-experiments/builds/2941618).

My maven version is

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_30, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-60-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I got this error when i tried to build with maven

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:license-maven-plugin:3:check (check-licenses) on project neo4j-kernel: Some files do not have the expected license header -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:license-maven-plugin:3:check (check-licenses) on project neo4j-kernel: Some files do not have the expected license header

First i tried to build in windows, then in ubuntu 12.04 , in both i got the same errors.

Below is the error stack trace

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:license-maven-plugin:3:check (check-licenses) on project neo4j-kernel: Some files do not have the expected license header -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:license-maven-plugin:3:check (check-licenses) on project neo4j-kernel: Some files do not have the expected license header
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Some files do not have the expected license header
    at com.google.code.mojo.license.LicenseCheckMojo.execute(LicenseCheckMojo.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
```

Now How can i solve this problem? Even though it is same error as in this SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456806/neo4j-clean-build-failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [neo4j github documentation](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j)

When building on Windows, use `-Dlicensing.skip` to avoid problems related to line endings.

The **license header check can be skipped** by appending the following to the command line: `-Dlicense.skip=true`

Comment: same err in linux too. and why is it throwing it?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Java 7**

Build the `community/license-check` submodule first.

Comment: still same error. Is there anything wrong in the steps i followed. Could u check this link [here](http://ajoeblk.blogspot.in/2014/04/neo4j-community-build-error.html) and where have i gone wrong.